# Mysql - Update Query with a Unique Key - After Slide_id=4

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c04ff7/2 (I am not sure how to copy the code here on StackOverflow as a SQL Fiddle)

What I tried manually is to update the Slide_id to 5 but it throws uniqueness error.

What I am trying to do is Update the table `course` such that FROM `slide_id=3 onwards every slide_id is incremented to 1 example slide_id=4 would be 5 slide_id=5 would be 6 and so on`

Is that possible through an Update statement, without throwing a Unique key error

```html
CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slide_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `course`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `slide_id` (`slide_id`,`course_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `course`
--
ALTER TABLE `course`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1026;
  

INSERT INTO `course` (`id`, `slide_id`, `course_id`) VALUES
(489, 1, 6),
(490, 2, 6),
(491, 3, 6),
(492, 4, 6),
(493, 5, 6),
(494, 6, 6),
(495, 7, 6),
(496, 8, 6),
(497, 9, 6),
(498, 10, 6),
(499, 11, 6),
(500, 12, 6),
(501, 13, 6),
(502, 14, 6),
(507, 15, 6),
(509, 16, 6),
(511, 17, 6),
(512, 18, 6),
(513, 19, 6),
(517, 20, 6),
(518, 21, 6),
(520, 22, 6),
(521, 23, 6),
(522, 24, 6),
(524, 25, 6),
(525, 26, 6),
(526, 27, 6),
(527, 28, 6),
(528, 29, 6),
(529, 30, 6),
(531, 31, 6),
(532, 32, 6),
(533, 33, 6),
(1025, 34, 6);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `ORDER BY` clause so it starts from the highest, that way it won't create any duplicates:

```
UPDATE course SET slide_id = slide_id + 1
WHERE slide_id >= 3
ORDER BY slide_id DESC
```

If your updates weren't so ordered, you could use a solution like [Updating table with unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538777/updating-table-with-unique-column)

Comment: This looks more appetizing than the alternative of dropping the unique constraint just for the update +1.